# MongoDB: Updating every document in a collection

Tags: python, mongodb, nosql

How can I add few elements to an array in every document in a collection?

I know how to update documents, but I don't know how to update every document in a collection.

For example, I have a document like this one:

**Document**

```py
{
    "user": 123456789,

    "packs": {
        "normal": 0,
        "rare": 0, 
    }
}
```

Let's say that I updated my bot and now every player should also have a `"super-rare": 0` element in his document. How can I achieve this? I'm using MongoDB Atlas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this done with simple update. If you want to update all documents, specify empty condition {} and multi: true like below

```
db.usertest.update( {}, {$set: {"packs.super-rare": 0}}, false, true)
```

Empty {} - To match all documents
false - upsert
true - multi (update multiple documents)