# How to update every single document in a MongoDB collection?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I know this is probably a duplicate but the solutions on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57708184/mongodb-updating-every-document-in-a-collection) didn't work for me so I decided to repeat it.

I am trying to put a new field on every single document in my database without loosing any data. I searched around a lot and found this code.

```js
           let res = await client.guildData.updateMany({  }, {$set: {testData: false}}, { upsert: true, multi: true })

            console.log(res.nModified)
```

However, when I run this code, nothing happens and `0` logs in the console that it didn't find anything to update, when in reality there is `9` documents it should update.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: are you using Node.Js MongoDB driver or mongoose for connection creation ? You don't need these `{ upsert: true, multi: true }` if you use `.updateMany()` you don't need `multi : true` & as there 9 docs already present in Coll & is no filter in query then `upsert : true` is not needed. Just print `nMatched` as well, though these shouldn't impact updates you can remove them, having `$set` also shouldn't impact update. Did you check your connection to DB is to right DB & collection ?

Comment: @whoami Using Mongoose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically what I originally posted, but @Vishnu suggested I added it to the schema and changed the code to this and now it works fine :)

```js
let thisThing = await client.guildData.updateMany( { }, {$set:{ guildWhiteList: [] }}, { useFindAndModify: false});

            console.log(thisThing)
```

Thanks for your help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

In `Mongoose` you don't need to specify the `$set`. So you can replace `{$set: {testData: false}}` with just `{testData: false}` [Documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.updateMany)

```js
Model.updateMany({}, { field: 'value'}, {upsert: true})
```

Comment: Tried this, still logging 0 in the console and nothing has changed.

Comment: I'd like to note that I'm trying to create something that doesn't exist in every document

Comment: @thetechguy61705: If you want to insert a new doc in no matching docs are found, then need to add `upsert: true`. I have updated my answer

Comment: I want to insert a new field into any EXISTING document in the mongo db. There is still nothing happening when that is run and the number logged is `0`

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using Mongoose or Node.js Mongodb driver?

Comment: I am using Mongoose

Comment: Okay. Do you have the new field that you are trying to add in the Schema?

Comment: Yes. It's in the schema. I want to update every document with the new field so I can allow them to edit the new setting.